# Postgres export via copy script doesn't like json with quotes on import

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to migrate some json blocks stored inside a Postgres database using the scripts below.  They work fine in most cases but fails on a few data sets(I think ones where I double quotes in the json).  Basically I am trying to promote some individual approved blocks of json to the prod database using an export script that copies out the data to file and an import script that locates the destination node of json in the destination database and rewrites that node with my new data appended.

I think those data sets that fail are the ones where the json data contains double quotes  in the data.  An example of how the json with quotes is exports is shown here.    I think the issue is the way the copy function is writing out(escaping) this data.   My reason for this guess is 1)Only records that fail seem to be ones where quotes in the data  2)A few json tools failed when parsing the json in the area where the quotes were escaped.
`"description": "See the chapter \\"Key fields\\" for a general description of keys.`

How can I adjust my scripts to be more friendly to what type of data is stored in the json?

Export

```
psql -h demo_ip -c "\COPY (select f_values from view_export_f where id = '$id' and f_kind='$f_kind') TO '/tmp/demo.json'"
```

Import

```
psql -h prod_ip -ef "import.psql" -v ex="$ex"
```

import.psql

```
\set json_block `cat /tmp/demo.json`

UPDATE data
SET value= jsonb_set(value, '{json_location}', value->'json_location' || (:'json_block'), true) where id=(:'ex')
```

Comment: Can you show an example of ```f_values``` from ```view_export_f```? To me it looks like it is escaping '\'. Remember also that the output from  ```COPY TO```(the base for \copy) is   meant to be read back by ```COPY FROM``` which would undo escaping and quoting. So it might be better to ```COPY FROM``` the data into a staging table and ```UPDATE``` from there.

Comment: Instead of using `\COPY` try to retrieve the value "as is" like `psql -XAqt -h demo_ip -c "select f_values from view_export_f where id = '$id' and f_kind='$f_kind'" > /tmp/demo.json` See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) the meaning of the `-XAqt` options.